# In ANT, can replacefilter token be a wildcard?

Tags: regex, ant

Like in:

```
 <replace file="${src}/index.html" token="&lt;/copyright>beginning text*end text&lt;copyright>" value="wombat"/>
```

Where "</copyright>beginning text*end text<copyright>" is some kind of string that I don't know the middle content of.

I've got a situation where I'm not 100% sure that the text I want to replace will be the same everytime.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match patterns, use the `replaceregexp` task. See https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html.

It has pretty much the same usage syntax but accepts regular expressions as the match string.